# How do I remove light fixture mount?

Tags: light-fixture

I want to remove the box used to mount a light and replace with heavy duty mount. I disconnected the wired. I am not able to get the box out. How is mounted ? I tried twisting and pulling - did not apply too much force.

[image]

Comment: It ought to be held by two screws - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpu3q.jpg - which it doesn't appear to be...

Comment: I have removed the two screws. The box moves freely but something seems to be holding it.

Comment: Is the cable held(clamped) to the box or just in a opening?

Comment: There is, most likely, a clamp of some sort, either in the box or just on the other side of the box holding the wire to the box. That will allow the box to wiggle on the wire, but there shouldn't be enough slack in the ceiling to allow the box to come fully out. Provide a picture of where the wire goes through the box.

Comment: I use hangers to span the distance between joists many of these are attached to the back of the box if you don’t have attic access you may have to cut out a section of the drywall

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. Like Tetsujin suggests above the box was held by a "C" clamp to the horizontal bar. For some reason the clamp was still clinging to the rail even after removing the screws holding it. I had to wiggle the box real hard to separate the clamp from the railing and set free the box. I have to add that I also pushed the wire from the box- ie making sure the box is totally free to move.